# Create result sets from matches across 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a set of results in table 1

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col 3    Result
A        B        C        1
A        B        D        2
A        B        D        3
A        B        E        4
A        B        E        5
A        B        F        6
```

and a set of conditions in table 2

```
Col 1    Col 2    Col 3
A        B        C
A        B        D
A        B        E
```

how do I return a table of 'Result Sets' (or grouped results) in T-SQL to identify all the possible combinations of results from table 1 where all conditions in table 2 are met?

```
Result Set    Result
1             1
1             2
1             4

2             1
2             2
2             5

3             1
3             3
3             4

4             1
4             3
4             5
```

EDIT: To clarify, the 'Result Set' value in the output table would be generated in the T-SQL to identify each set of results.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also it's not clear how the results you want are related to your two tables.

Comment: I can achieve the desired outcome using a cursor however I cannot use this approach for performance reasons due to the size of the data sets.